# Removing sample that is the only one of its kind with regards to one variable?

Tags: regression

I have a dataset with 45 samples. I am looking to use the rms package and fit an ols model in the following manner:

```
final_score ~ rcs(baseline_score,3) + age + sex + biological_variable + numberoftreatmentsessions
```

From a "degrees of freedom spent" perspective, I have one sample in which they described their sex as other than male or female. Accordingly, for sex, I have 3 categories.

My question is when dealing with categorical variables in which one factor consists of a very small portion of the overall sample, would it be better to keep that sample, or remove them? From a practical/real world perspective, it seems wrong to exclude such samples, but I'm curious from a statistical perspective (especially when dealing with a small sample like I am), if there is a recommendation?